# how to share embedded local server's video or remote server's video on Facebook or Google+?

Tags: facebook, video, google-plus

If we have a embedded video with any player or video tag in our site (not YouTube video) or video can be hosted on another server and if we want to share it on Facebook or Google+, how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this article](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player) worth a bit of your time.  Note:  You may need to have a working SSL certificate on your server in order for it to work right.